# How to implement a survey?

Tags: python, excel, survey

I want to build a survey consisting of some question (<10) with 4 options each. I tried different ways (Microsoft survey, SurveyMonkey or Excel etc.) and finally turned to Python so that i get to learn something and achieve exactly what i want. I was able to get the questions and options listed properly with lists and loops. Now i want to save them in either Excel or something else like a database. Trying to refrain from Xls because i will send this survey to around 50 people and Excel may give some hazards. I am not really sure if its possible at all but the idea is to create an .exe in Python and share it with the group and when they provide the answers (while running the .exe), these answers should be recorded somewhere. I am not looking for too much analytics or super reports but it will be welcome to have. Sample code below what i wrote :

```
print("enter your name")
name=input()

print("how many teams you play for ?")
number_of_teams=int(input())
s=number_of_teams
print("you have to fill this form",s,"times")

//list of question in my survey

questions_list = ["Q1.A ?","Q2. B? ", "Q3. C?", "Q4. D?", "Q5. E ?", "Q6. F 
?","Q7. G ? "]

//list of options for each of those questions

answers_list = [["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],
               ["A.1 ", " B.2 ", " C.3 "," D.4 "],]

i=0
while i<s:
    print("enter your team name")
    team=input()
    for questions, answers in zip(questions_list, answers_list):
        print(questions + '\n' + ''.join(answers)+'\n')
        get_answer = input()
        print('\n')
    i=i+1
```

No third party libraries can be used (because of data sharing issues).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to create an .exe with python using PyInstaller. I'd suggest creating a python program that interacts with a `SQLite` database. Then, use PyInstaller to convert it into an .exe program.

I've provided a few links that might be useful: [Python Excel Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial), [Python SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/) and [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much, i am evaluating the options suggested by you. SQLlite will support a db which i could create in a shared location and then i save the users' input in the same to be fetched later to review those answers ?

Comment: Possible, it all depends on how are you designing it. I've learn the basics from of building a desktop interface using `Tkinter` that interacts with `SQLite`, Here's the course [link](https://www.udemy.com/the-python-mega-course/).

Comment: Hello again, i just completed my application as i wanted. I placed the SQLite db file in a shared location and tested it too. It worked and check the concurrent user entries as well. You think you can guide me in a direction wherein i can use some authentication for each users who will use the survey.exe ?  I heard LDAP could be used in some way but not sure , will be great if you can guide me in a direction again. Thanks very much.